# How do I differentiate the equation $\frac{dR}{d\theta}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure how this solution works, and I've been trying for a long time now realising that I need some guidance or maybe even a step by step explanation.

[image]

Comment: Can you use the implicit function theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a function of the form
$$
0=h+R(θ)u(θ)+R(θ)^2v(θ)
$$
Now apply the product rule and sort the derivatives so that one group has those with $R'$,
$$
0=\Bigl(u(θ)+2R(θ)v(θ) \Bigr)R'(θ)+R(θ)\Bigl(u'(θ)+R(θ)v'(θ)\Bigr)
$$

---

The remainder is differentiation rules for elementary functions, 
$$
u(θ)=\tan(θ)\implies u'(θ)=\frac1{\cos^2θ}=\sec^2θ
$$
and
$$
v(θ)=c\sec^2θ=\frac{c}{\cos^2θ}\implies v'(θ)=\frac{2c\sinθ}{\cos^3θ}=2c\sec^2θ\tanθ
$$